# Listener working, Binding not

Tags: javafx

Here is a minimal working example:

```
public class FF {

    @Test
    public void test01() {
    final ListProperty p = new SimpleListProperty(FXCollections.observableArrayList());
    p.addListener((ListChangeListener) c -> {
        System.err.println("Listener here..");
    });
    Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
        System.err.println("Binding here");
        return null;
    }, p);

    p.add("hans");
    }

    @Test
    public void test02() {
    final ListProperty p = new SimpleListProperty(FXCollections.observableArrayList());
    final ListProperty p2 = new SimpleListProperty(FXCollections.observableArrayList());
    p.addListener((ListChangeListener) c -> {
        System.err.println("Listener 1 here..");
    });
    p2.addListener((ListChangeListener) c -> {
        System.err.println("Listener 2 here..");
    });
    final ObjectBinding ob = Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
        System.err.println("Binding here");
        return null;
    }, p);
    p2.bind(ob);
    p.add("hans");

    }

}
```

The second test looks like expected, but for the first test, the output is just "Listener here..". Why is the binding not working in this case?

What is the difference between the anonymous Listener and the anonymous Binding?

Answer (score 3):

You had created Binding object but didn't bind anything through it, so it optimized itself to do nothing.

Add any random action to see "binding here..." output. E.g.:

```
    ObjectBinding<ObservableList> ob = Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
        System.err.println("Binding here");
        return null;
    }, p);
    ob.addListener((o) -> {
        System.out.println("random action");
    });
```